# Django running fine outside Docker but never starts within Docker, how to find issue?

Tags: django, debugging, docker

I had a working Django project that had built and deployed many images over the last few weeks. My django project kept working fine when ran as "python manage.py runserver" and the Docker images kept being built fine (all successful builds). However the django app now doesn't deploy. **What could be the issue and where should I start to look for it? I've tried the logs but they only say "Starting Django" without actually starting the service**

I use github and have gone back to previous versions of the code and none of them now work, even though the code is exactly the same. It also fails to deploy the Django server on AWS Elastic Beanstalk infrastructure which is my ultimate goal with this code.

start.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Starting Django
cd TN_API
exec python ../manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7.13-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /TN_API

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /TN_API

# COPY startup script into known file location in container
COPY start.sh /start.sh

# Install requirements
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# EXPOSE port 8000 to allow communication to/from server
EXPOSE 8000

# CMD specifcies the command to execute to start the server running.
CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

Commands:
sudo docker run -d tn-api
sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
d28115a919f9        tn-api              "/start.sh"         11 seconds ago      Up 8 seconds        8000/tcp            festive_darwin

sudo docker logs [container id]
Starting Django

(doesn't do the whole:
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 06, 2017 - 20:54:36
Django version 1.10.5, using settings 'TN_API.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.)

Comment: `docker ps` and `docker logs` what do they say? is the container exited?

Comment: I suspect the issue with the `TN_API` folder, can you share your directory structure as in Dockerfile `TN_API` folder is your work directory and your `script.sh` also points to `cd TN_API`.

Comment: Added edits on main post

Comment: main folder
-- Dockerfile
-- start.sh
-- manage.py
-- TN_API
-----settings.py
-----urls.py
-----wsgi.py

Answer (score 0):

I changed several things and although it doesn't work locally it seems to work fine when deployed to AWS. I still don't get the feedback I used to get such as below but that's ok. I can hit the server and it works. Thank you all for your help.

Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced). August 06, 2017 - 20:54:36 Django version 1.10.5, using settings 'TN_API.settings' Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the path is wrong for the `manage.py` script in `/start.sh`.

Your start.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Starting Django
cd TN_API
exec python ../manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Seeing that you set `WORKDIR` to you project directory in the Dockerfile, the `start.sh` script is actually run from inside the project directory - which means it is actually doing this:

```
cd /TN_API               # WORKDIR directive in Dockerfile
echo Starting Django     # from the start.sh script
cd /TN_API/TN_API        # looking for TN_API within your current pwd
exec python /TN_API/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000  # goes up a level (..) to look for manage.py
```

So it could be that your context for running `runserver` is off.
You can avoid this path jumping by rewriting your Dockerfile to include an CMD directive as follows:

```
FROM python:2.7.13-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /TN_API

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /TN_API

# Install requirements
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# EXPOSE port 8000 to allow communication to/from server
EXPOSE 8000

# CMD specifcies the command to execute to start the server running.
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Here using `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` will work since you set the `WORKDIR` to your project directory already. So you wouldn't need your `start.sh` script necessarily.